# How to make a non nullable string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use a string like this `Memory.read<string>();` issue is that string has to be non Nullable how do i fix this? Memory requires a struct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# creating a non-nullable string. Is it possible? Somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554003/c-sharp-creating-a-non-nullable-string-is-it-possible-somehow)

Comment: Are you talking about [`Memory<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1?view=netcore-3.1) struct?